# Select, copy and paste form Tkinter Python Layout Grid

Tags: python, select, tkinter, copy, paste

I need to select, to copy and to paste some information of my form tkinter. But I cant do it. I want to copy the name 'Angelina Jolie' and paste anywhere. How I can do it? I need to do this with Grid Layout. I found some tutorials with pack and place. But I'm only interested in the Lyaout Grid

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Form:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def form(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('850x600')
        self.root.title("PVE - Formulário Estudar")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='light blue', scrollregion=(0, 0, 1500, 3300))
        self.canvas.bind('<Enter>', self._bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind('<Leave>', self._unbound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        f = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="light blue")

        # you need to create a window into the canvas for the widget to scroll
        self.canvas.create_window((5, 5), window=f, anchor="nw")

        yvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        xvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)

        yvbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        yvbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        xvbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        xvbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=yvbar.set, xscrollcommand=xvbar.set)

        ttk.Label(f, width=20, text='Name: ', font='Arial 12 bold', background="light blue", anchor='w')\
        .grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        ttk.Label(f, width=40, text='Angelina Jolie', font='Arial 12 bold', foreground="blue",
              background="light blue").grid(column=1, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def _bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Form()
    a.form()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to copy the value to the clipboard or you meant to ask how to set the value of another element to the value of an existing element, however, I added a copy button that does both, take a look at the code below for how I did it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pyperclip


class Form:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def copy_name(self):
        # Get the current label value 
        user_name = self.name_label['text']
        # Copy the value to the clipboard 
        pyperclip.copy(user_name)
        # Update "paste" the value to the second label 
        self.copy_name_label.config(text=user_name)
        
        print("{} was copied to your clipboard".format(user_name))

    def form(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('850x600')
        self.root.title("PVE - Formulário Estudar")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='light blue', scrollregion=(0, 0, 1500, 3300))
        self.canvas.bind('<Enter>', self._bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind('<Leave>', self._unbound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        f = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="light blue")

        # you need to create a window into the canvas for the widget to scroll
        self.canvas.create_window((5, 5), window=f, anchor="nw")

        yvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        xvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)

        yvbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        yvbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        xvbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        xvbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=yvbar.set, xscrollcommand=xvbar.set)

        ttk.Label(f, width=20, text='Name: ', font='Arial 12 bold', background="light blue", anchor='w') \
            .grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        self.name_label = ttk.Label(f, width=40, text='Angelina Jolie', font='Arial 12 bold', foreground="blue",
                                    background="light blue")
        self.name_label.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.copy_name_label = ttk.Label(f, width=40, text='', font='Arial 12 bold', foreground="blue",
                                         background="light blue")
        self.copy_name_label.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        copy_button = tk.Button(f, text="Copy", command=self.copy_name)
        copy_button.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def _bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Form()
    a.form()
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to select and copy the name "Agelina Jolie" directly from the form and paste it wherever he wishes. This Code does not work.

Comment: Honestly not sure what exactly u trynna do, are u looking to use text box instead of label?!

Comment: Thanks Marsilinou, I got what was needed.  I'll post the solution below

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky Try not to use txtspk(_"u"_) on this community. Take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105497/how-to-deal-with-user-using-txt-spk)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution for my problem in this tutorial:
http://www.booneputney.com/development/tkinter-copy-to-clipboard/

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Form:

name = "Angelina Jolie"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def copy_text_to_clipboard(self, event):
        self.name = event.widget.get("1.0", 'end-1c')  # get field value from event, but remove line return at end
        self.root.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
        self.root.clipboard_append(self.name)  # append new value to clipbaord

    def form(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('850x600')
        self.root.title("PVE - Formulário Estudar")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='light blue', scrollregion=(0, 0, 1500, 3300))
        self.canvas.bind('<Enter>', self._bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind('<Leave>', self._unbound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        f = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="light blue")

        # you need to create a window into the canvas for the widget to scroll
        self.canvas.create_window((5, 5), window=f, anchor="nw")

        yvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        xvbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)

        yvbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        yvbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        xvbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        xvbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=yvbar.set, xscrollcommand=xvbar.set)

        ttk.Label(f, width=20, text='Name: ', font='Arial 12 bold', background="light blue", anchor='w')\
        .grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        text_name = Text(f, width=40, height=1, font='Arial 12 bold', background="light blue", foreground="blue",
                     borderwidth=0)
        text_name.insert(1.0, self.name)
        text_name.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Bind left click on text widget to copy_text_to_clipboard() function
        text_name.bind("<Button-1>", self.copy_text_to_clipboard)

        self.root.mainloop()


     def _bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Form()
    a.form()
```

Comment: I dont recommend you actually clear the `clipboard` as what if the user is having somethibg important in their clipboard stored and you clear it without their permission